# Set first visible item in Android gridview completely seen

Tags: android

i have gridview with two column 
user can scroll vertically  to see  gridview items 
the problem is when user scrolling is finished
the first visible row is not completely seen .i want to  set top of first visible row to top of gridview so first row is comletely visible

can anyone help me?

Update:
the first item is 
[image]
and the second item is 
[image]

but after scroll we see 
[image]

Comment: So you want a header?

Comment: no . just show item completely .when  scroll finish at midlle of row

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
grid.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int scrollState) {
                //this is the state when scroll finish
                if(scrollState==SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
                    //the first visible item is the first (even partially) visbile item
                    //setSelection will scroll the grid to the beginning of such item
                    grid.setSelection(firstVisibleItem);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView arg0, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I use RecyclerView, and i hope it's good for you!

```
mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
mListRV= (RecyclerView).findViewById(R.id.list_rv);
mListRV.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

mListRV.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        View v = mLayoutManager.getChildAt(0);
                        int offsetTop = v.getTop();
                        int offsetBottom = v.getBottom();
                        int height = (offsetBottom - offsetTop);
                        if(offsetTop >= -height/2) {
                            mListRV.smoothScrollBy(0, offsetTop);
                        } else {
                            mListRV.smoothScrollBy(0, height + offsetTop);
                        }
                    } 
                }
            });
```

With this code, when you finish scroll, if the first visible item only show a part in recyclerView. It will auto scroll to show full item. You can use:

```
mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, offset);
```

But it is so fast, the user can be confused. And you will not need use customLayoutManager to edit scroll's properties.

Hope that helps for you!