# Cannot visible completely row of gridview after doing scrolling on grid view

Tags: android

I have implemented GriView which contains 10 rows and 3 columns.when we are doing scrolling vertically on grid view. Item view of gridview is visible partially. Please find my code in below.

```
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
        currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;

    }

    private void isScrollCompleted() {
        if (gridView.getLastVisiblePosition() == gridView.getAdapter().getCount() - 1
                && gridView.getChildAt(gridView.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= gridView.getHeight()) {
            if (this.currentVisibleItemCount > 0 && currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
             gridView.smoothScrollToPosition(-1);
              }
            }
          }
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        currentScrollState = scrollState;
        isScrollCompleted();
     }

}
```

Comment: is your gridview inside scrollview?

Comment: Can you see my answer here [Set first visible item in Android gridview completely seen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261134/set-first-visible-item-in-android-gridview-completely-seen?answertab=active#tab-top)